# From 2.2 to 2.3, Spring Boot adds back the requirement of @Component or @EnableConfigurationProperties for @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I recently upgraded a Spring Boot project from version 2.2.0 to 2.3.1, but I noticed an error that I was getting prior to Spring 2.2.0.

> Not registered via @EnableConfigurationProperties, marked as Spring component, or scanned via @ConfigurationPropertiesScan

On

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("sftp")
public class SftpProperties {
    String host;
    String user;
    String password;
    String baseDir;
}
```

In earlier Spring Boot version -- I believe 2.0.2 or something -- I had above class annotated with `@Component` so that it gets picked up during classpath scanning. But starting with 2.2, I read that it wasn't necessary anymore therefore I removed `@Component`. This seems to be a subtle improvement but as of 2.3.x, it is no longer supported. Why is this the case or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`@ConfigurationProperties` does not make a class a Spring Component. You also need to add `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` in your application to enable scanning for classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

See the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#configurationproperties-scanning)

Answer (score 0):

Before Spring 2.2, main class should have @EnableConfigurationProperties(SftpProperties .class) or use @Configuration above your SftpProperties class.

But after 2.2 Spring finds and registers @ConfigurationProperties classes via classpath scanning so there is no need for these annotations, you can just have @ConfigurationPropertiesScan("property package path") annotation to scan custom locations for configuration property classes.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.app.properties")
public class DemoApplication { 
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args); 
    } 
}
```